# Why Elastic Beanstalk instance stop responding

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer

I have a nodeJS app deployed to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk and uses Application Load Balancer.

The problems is - once in a while instance stop responding. When I try to get logs, I see:

> requestEnvironmentInfo is starting

and a timeout as a result.

I simply cannot access logs, even when I do `eb shh` I get:

> INFO: Attempting to open port 22.
>   INFO: SSH port 22 open.
>   INFO: Running ssh -i /Users/Rostyslav/.ssh/cards-eb-keypair ec2-user@xx.xxx.xxx.xx
>   ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
>   ERROR: An error occurred while running: ssh.

I also have set up logs auto-transfer to S3, but after instance get stacked - no new logs there anymore.

If I kill the EC2 instance and Load Balancer creates a new one and problem get fixed. However in usually ~1 day the same thing is happening.

Any ideas about why it is happening? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using t2 instances?

Comment: I use a free tier, so yes, t2.micro.

Comment: Check your instance's CPU credits in CloudWatch. I'm guessing you are running out of CPU credits, which means your website is too CPU intensive to run successfully inside the free tier.

Comment: Wow, thank you Mark. I see an alert and that NetworkOut thing is smoothly growing until I kill the instance. Does it mean my app always send something to clients? I guess it can be some issue with web sockets...